# SQL to assign random number based on percent

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a table with userId and username. I want to assign random numbers to each row based on percent. Eg: I want to assign 6, 7, 8 to each row. But 50% of the records should have 6 assigned. 45% rows should have 7 assigned and the remaining 5% rows should have 8 assigned.

Is there a way we can do this in SQL?

Output should be userid, username, random number.

Answer (score 2):

```
  select userid, username, case cast (dbms_random.value(0, 20) as int) 
    when 0 then 6
    when 1 then 6
    when 2 then 6
    when 3 then 6
    when 4 then 6
    when 5 then 6
    when 6 then 6
    when 7 then 6
    when 8 then 6
    when 9 then 6
    when 10 then 7
    when 11 then 7
    when 12 then 7
    when 13 then 7
    when 14 then 7
    when 15 then 7
    when 16 then 7
    when 17 then 7
    when 18 then 7
    when 19 then 8
    else -1 -- should never happen
 end as "RANDOM" 
   from mytable;
```

Because the values are generated randomly, this will not give you the 50/45/5 ratio exactly but should be close to it if you have a large number of rows (and the random number function is any good)

Another way is to `order by random` the rows and assign 6 to the first 50%, 7 to the next 45% and 8 to the remainder.  This will assure that you have the correct ratio:

```
with myset as (
    select userid, username
    from my_user_table
    order by dbms_random.value(0,1)
)
select * from
(
    select 
        userid, 
        username, 
        case when rownum <= (select count(*) from myset) * 0.50 then 6
            when rownum <= (select count(*) from myset) * 0.95 then 7
            else 8 
          end as random
    from myset) t
order by t.userid;
```

Comment: How about knocking some of the cases down a bit: 
select userid, username
      ,case when r.slot < 10 then 6
            when r.slot < 19 then 7
            else 8 end
  from mytable x
      ,(select dbms_random.value(0, 20) as slot from dual) r

Comment: I really, really distrust the comment "should never happen" in code. If it should never happen then why is it there? If it does occur then all you've done is not raise an error but mask the problem.

Comment: I've added a second example. @Glenn: Your method chooses only a single random number which causes *all* the rows to be assigned the same value.  I know my first example is a bit verbose but it illustrates a technique for solving the problem.  It's not my intent to gilt-edge the answer: OP can make it perfect for the themselves if they want to.

Comment: @Ben: It's not my intent to produce a perfect answer, just an answer that will give OP a clue as to how to proceed.  The reason I added the `should never happen` comment was to warn that there might be an edge-case that needs fixing: I didn't want to invest the extra effort myself to determine whether there was or not.  Let's leave something for the reader to figure out for themselves, shall we?

Comment: @AdrianPronk You are right. I do think your answer is good. I wasn't really trying to provide an alternate answer, just wondering if there were a way to do it less verbose. And as you pointed out, what I stuffed in the comments is incorrect. Lesson to me to try things out before putting foot in mouth :). The second approach is interesting as well, but I would prefer the first using a select userid, username, random as the subquery.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If PL/SQL is an option:

```
DECLARE
  RAND number := dbms_random.value;
BEGIN
  IF RAND <= 0.50 THEN
     RAND := 6;
  ELSIF RAND <= 0.95 THEN
     RAND := 7;
  ELSE
     RAND := 8;
  END IF;
  dbms_output.put_line(RAND); -- this line can be changed by the 'insert'
END;
```

Comment: Thank you everyone. I personally the plsql block. It is a better algorithm. !!

Answer (score 1):

I find that the best way to assign a random number is via a pseudo-random number generator:

1. Enumerate each row
2. Calculate a formula to get a pseudo-random number
3. Use this to select the appropriate range

For your case:

```
SELECT t.*, 
       ( CASE 
           WHEN Mod(rownum * 71 + 107, 257) < .5 * 257 THEN 6 
           WHEN Mod(rownum * 63 + 107, 257) BETWEEN 0.5 * 257 AND 0.95 * 257 
         THEN 7 
           ELSE 8 
         END ) AS val 
FROM   (SELECT t.*, 
               Row_number() 
                 OVER ( 
                   partition BY NULL) AS rownum 
        FROM   t) t
```

The idea is that multiplying by one prime, adding another, and taking the remainder via a third is a pretty good approximation of a random number.  Not perfect, but good enough for most purposes.

Also, the percentages here are approximations.